# Guessing the upper bound of an interval from 10 independent uniform draws

Tags: probability, game-theory, puzzle

Suppose you draw an integer $N$ uniformly in $[1, 1000]$. Then draw 10 integers $(X_1, ..., X_{10})$ uniformly from $[1,N]$. Suppose you are shown the 10 numbers, and the game is you win \$1 if you guess $N$ right and loose \$1 each time you fail.

1. What could be your strategy ?
2. Now what if you win \$N if you guess correctly ?
3. Now what if you win \$N/2 ?

Comment: Don't play game $1$ because it's obviously $-$EV. Game $2$ and game $3$ are probably $+$EV, so I would play those.

Answer (score 1):

[Partial answer]

The MLE and MAP estimators of $N$ in this case are both $\max_i X_i$.

Let $p_n := P(N = \max_i X_i \mid N=n)$ be the conditional probability of success given $N=n$. You can show that this equals $p_n = 1 - \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{10}$.

Let $w_n$ be the amount you win when $N=n$. In the three parts, we have $w_n$ being $1$, $n$, and $n/2$ respectively.

The expected payoff is $\sum_{n=1}^{1000} (w_np_n - (1 - p_n)) = -1000 + \sum_{n=1}^{1000} (w_n+1) p_n$.

Not sure how to handle the $p_n$. Some crude approximations for $p_n$ (for large $n$) are $10/n$ and $1-e^{-10/n}$, but neither seem helpful.

Numerical results: the expected payoffs of this estimator are approximately $-899$, $8799$, and $3924$ respectively.

Comment: If there were not the information: $N$ is uniformly in $[1,...,1000]$, you might be right that the estimator of $N$ is $\max_i x_i$. However, it's not the case.

Comment: @NN2 Even if you use the information about the prior distribution for $N$, the MAP estimator is still $\max_i X_i$. What estimator would you suggest instead?

Comment: I agree with @angryavian.
Given $n \in [1, 1000]$, $f(n) = P_{N|X_1, \dots, X_{10}}(n|x_1,\dots,x_{10}) = \frac{P(X_1 = x_1, \dots, X_{10} = x_{10} | N = n) \times P(X_1 = x_1, \dots, X_{10} = x_{10})}{P(N = n)} = 1000 \times \frac{1}{n^{10}} \times \frac{1}{N^{10}}$. This is $0$ for $n < max_i X_i$ and this is maximized by n = max_i X_i.

Comment: A strategy would be to first guess $max_i X_i$ and then increase up to 1000 until we guess right. That gives an expected return of $ER = P(N = max_i X_i) - \sum_{k = 2}^{1000 - max_i X_i}(k-1) \times P(N = max_i X_i + k)$. I think this is equal to $ER = (1 - (\frac{N-1}{N})^{10}) - \sum_{k = 2}^{1000 - max_i X_i}(k-1)(1 - \frac{N - k}{N})^{10})$

Answer (score 1):

Fix values $x_1,\ldots,x_{10}$. Now for any $n\in[\max_ix_i,1000]$ we have
$$P(X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_{10}=x_{10}\mid N=n)=\frac{1}{n^{10}},$$
and by Bayes' rule, noting that $P(N=n)$ is constant,
$$P(N=n\mid X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_{10}=x_{10})=\frac{C}{n^{10}}$$
for some $C$ that does not depend on $n$.

The three games come down to maximising $f(n)P(N=n\mid X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_{10}=x_{10})$ for $f(n)=2,1+n,1+n/2$ respectively. In each case $f(n)P(N=n\mid X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_{10}=x_{10})=an^{-10}+bn^{-9}$ for some $a,b\geq 0$ and is decreasing in $n$ for $n\in[\max_ix_i,1000]$, so we should just guess the maximum of the $X_i$.